# Is it expected behavior to manually reindex a Frame after sorting? Is this a bug?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, indexing, reindex

I have a time series of stellar flux that is periodic in nature. For this data I created a DataFrame with a time column and flux column.

```
file: Path = localdir / file_path.csv
est_period: float = #number_I_estimated
df = DataFrame(file, names=['t','f'])
df['stack_t'] = df['t'] % est_period

stacked = df[['stack','f']].sort_values(by='stack')
```

I create a new column by applying the modulus `%` operation to the time `'t'` series with the estimated period and stack the series on top of itself by calling `df.sort_values(by='stack_t')`.

I noticed that `DataFrame.sort_values(inplace=True)` seems to not reindex the data set. If you sort the data set, then find the minimum of `f` over `mask=stacked['stack_t']>somenumber` then it turns out that `argmin(stacked[mask]['f'])` returns the index from `df`, not from `stacked`.

To get this to work it turns out that I have to manually reindex the array:

```
stacked = df[['stack','f']].sort_values(by='stack').reindex(range(0,len(df)))
```

Is this expected behavior? `.sort_values` already returns a copy of `df`. Why is the copy not reindexed?

Comment: So I don't. What I want is to take the resulting sorted array and do some comparison tests to make simple masks `mask=(val1<df['stack_t'])&(df['stack_t']<val2)`, then apply those masks to `df['f'][masks]` and then apply `.argmin()`. In other words I am trying to use a simple peak locator. I want to then center all these stacked points by passing the obtained value to `df['stack_t'].loc[minval]` and shift the peak to the center with `df['stack_t']-centerval`.

Comment: The __problem__ is that this simple idea keeps yielding different random minvals depending on `val1` and `val2` which seems to be due to `argmin` choosing the wrong index?

Comment: I think I understood your problem the other way around... So, when you sort the values, the indexes are sorted together with the values? So if the indexes were `[0,1,2]` and the values `[10,4,8]`, after sorting you get values `[4,8,10]` and indexes `[1,2,0]` instead of `[0,1,2]`. Is this the problem?

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I am not sure exactly what is going on but it is pervasive and affects numpy and pandas. I cannot use `np.find_peaks`. Apparently there is `.idxmin()`

Answer (score 1):

That's a perfectly normal and desirable behavior of `DataFrame.sort()`, and not a bug.

Indexes are *usually* thought as identifiers for data points, not as indicators of position (you can think on them as dictionary keys). So, when you sort the data or select a subset of it, you want to keep the correspondent Id for each point, even if this breaks the original sequential order (if there was some).

IMO, the solution you found is precisely the reason because `.reindex()` exists: to solve those cases where you don't want to keep the original association.